# c++: cin.getline() cutting off input before specified carriage return

Tags: c++, arrays, iostream, cin

I'm trying to figure out how to use cin.getline() correctly and have run into a problem that I can't find an answer to.

I'm doing an assignment for a course I'm taking, and I need to be able to use cin to get whole lines of text from the user, including whitespaces. We can't use strings, we have to use character arrays (that's a requirement for the assignment). I decided to just use cin.ignore() and cin.getline(ARRAY_NAME, '\n').

Here's my problem: cin.getline() seems to be picking up the white spaces fine, but for some reason it's cutting off my line and only storing the first 9 characters that are being input.

Here's the relevant code (the stuff related to the use of "cin" is isolated to the "menu" function I'm calling from main that gets input from the user so I don't think I need to trouble everyone with the rest of it):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

void menu(){
    char name[30];
    char description[50];
    char articleTitle[50];

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(); // Idk if both clear and ignore are necessary here
    cout << endl << "Enter name: ";
    cin.getline(name, '\n');
    cout << endl << "Enter description: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(description, '\n');
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(articleTitle, '\n');
    cin.ignore();
```

It's using all this stuff to build a class object and add it to a list, and it's supposed to print a success message if it works that says something like

```
cout << endl << "you added " << name << " to the list" << endl;
```

but what's happening is, if I enter more than 9 characters for any of those three character arrays, it prints the success message with "name" trimmed down to 9 characters and then exits the program.

I don't think it could have anything to do with the rest of my program because I don't edit any of the character arrays in any way after they're input, and it only breaks when I enter more than 9 characters for any of the three. If I enter 9 for "name" and 9 for "description" it'll still break as soon as I enter 10+ for "articleTitle"

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using the wrong function.  ord('\n') is 10.  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/).

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. I looked at countless pages of people's code on forums and everyone said it was either cin.getline(array_name, delimiter) or cin.getline(array_name, streamsize). I hadn't realized I needed cin.getline(array_name, streamsize, delimiter).

Comment: Lesson learned here: instead of reading hearsay of dubious accuracy on random forums, look up the actual formal specifications for library functions and classes. Knowing where to find, and how to read technical specifications is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you are absolutely right. lesson learned